# sql: how to take values one by one using join query?

Tags: mysql, sql

my query:

```
select  b.*,a.`USA`as fd_lat,b.`UK` as fd_lot  
from fdusa a 
join incident_uk b 
   on a.`FBI`=b.`FBI` 
   and b.STATE='MD' 
limit 0,5
```

I have a column name `INC_KEY`,

when the limit is 0,5. single result is displayed for 5 times. same incident key is dispalyed.

how to change the query as different incident key for the remaining values.

Comment: Are you looking for `random` keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the JOIN operation there is producing multiple similar results. If you join 2 tables

```
A   B
------
1   10
2   25
3   40


A   C 
------
1   x 
1   x
2   z
```

you will get

```
A B C 
-------
1 10 x
1 10 x
2 25 z
```

A quick fix would be to use DISTINCT in your SELECT clause, i.e.

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.*,a.`USA`as fd_lat,b.`UK` as fd_lot
```

If that doesn't suit you, you can always GROUP BY incident key and take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to sort the results by some other key or possibly randomly.  Put the `order by` clause before the `limit`:

```
order by rand()
```

Puts them in random order.  No guarantee they will be different, though.

A second approach is use `group by` to get different values for the different incident keys.  The following *happens* to work most of the time in MySQL, but is not guaranteed:

```
select  b.*,a.`USA`as fd_lat,b.`UK` as fd_lot  
from fdusa a 
join incident_uk b 
   on a.`FBI`=b.`FBI` 
   and b.STATE='MD'
group by inc_key
limit 0,5
```

This will return one row per inc_key (because of the `group by`).  The rest of the columns are arbitrarily chosen from the rows with the same value of inc_key.  In practice, the seem to come from the first row, although the documentation explicitly states that this is not guaranteed.  Nor is it guaranteed that they come from the same row.